# do they make a a exhauster fan for the 3inch double wall hot water exhaust pipe

Tags: water, gas, heater, exhaust

this is a older home with large trees. at night times we get exhaust gasses from the hot water heater and I would like to find a inline exhaust fan that I can install.

Comment: First get a CO detector so you wake up in the morning.  Will need more information about the heater, but I doubt a fan would last long and might cause more problems.  Clean the exhaust pipes to make sure they are not blocked.

Comment: "we get exhaust gasses"... in the house I presume? Is the water heater the only gas appliance, so you're sure it's that? What do large trees have to do with it? What's the condition of the flue? If it's an "older home", it's likely that the exhaust duct work is "older" too and might have some leaks in it due to rust, corrosion, or just un-taped/sealed connections sagging over time now letting fumes out. A fan would just push them out faster.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.